# Count sum of all list elements until condition is satisfied

Tags: kotlin

I faced the following problem: I have a list of objects. Let it be objects of the class Test:

```
data class Test(
    var status: String, // Can be EXPIRED, WAIT
    var amount: Float
)
```

The array is sorted, there are objects with the status `EXPIRED` in the beginning and after objects with the status `WAIT` located. I need to calculate the sum of all elements with the status `EXPIRED` (if they exist) and add to this sum amount of the first object with the type `WAIT` (if it exists). Now I have the following code:

```
 private fun getRestructuringAmountToPay(): Float {
        var i = 0
        var sum = 0F
        list?.forEachIndexed { iter, el ->
            if (el.status != RestructingItemStatus.WAIT) {
                i = iter
                sum += el.amount ?: 0F
            }
        }
        if (i + 1 < (list?.size ?: 0)) {
            sum += list?.get(i+1)?.amount ?: 0F
        }
        return sum
    }
```

But is there any way to improve this code and make it Kotlin-pretty? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You say you want to sum up all the items with status `WAIT`, but it seems that you're doing the opposite.

Comment: @Steve yes, sorry, updated the question

Answer (score 3):

since your list is sorted and  `EXPIRED` items are first you can use `firstOrNull`
to find the first item with `status == WAIT`

while you iterate over `EXPIRED` items you can use a simple variable to sum the `amount` and when you found the first `WAIT` item just assign the sum to `amount`

```
 var sum: Float = 0f
 list.firstOrNull {
     sum += it.amount
     it.status == "WAIT"
 }?.apply {
     this.amount = sum
 }
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  It blends the readability of my old-school solution with a more modern streaming style. I'm going to try to remember this as a template for the next time I get back to Kotlin programming.

Comment: @Steve thank you, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 2):

I would go old school and use a `for` loop rather than the `forEachIndexed` method so that I can `break` out of the loop when I hit the first `WAIT` entry.  I'd do something like this:

```
private fun getRestructuringAmountToPay(): Float {
    var sum = 0F
    for (el in list) {
        if (el.status == RestructingItemStatus.WAIT) {
            el.amount += sum
            break
        }
        else {
            sum += el.amount
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

This is a simple and elegant way to do the bare minimum amount of work without any extra iterations over the list.  If you're one of the "I have to cram everything into as few lines of code as possible" crowd, there are certainly more sophisticated and compact ways to go about this.  I often struggle to understand the actual advantage of such solutions.

Comment: I must agree with you

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to find all of the elements in the list with the status `"EXPIRED"`, that makes me think of `filter()`. When you say you want to sum them, that makes me think of `sumBy()`. And when you say you want to add that number to the first element in the list with the status `"WAIT"`, that makes me think of `first()`.

We can't actually use the normal `sumBy()` function because `Test.amount` is of type `Float`, so the closest we can do is use `sumByDouble()` and convert `amount` to a `Double`.

```
val expiredSum = list.filter { it.status == "EXPIRED" }.sumByDouble { it.amount.toDouble() }
val result = list.first { it.status == "WAIT" }.amount + expiredSum
```

If you don't want to throw an exception if there are no elements with the status `"WAIT"`, use `firstOrNull()` instead:

```
val expiredSum = list.filter { it.status == "EXPIRED" }.sumByDouble { it.amount.toDouble() }
val initialValue = list.firstOrNull { it.status == "WAIT" }?.amount ?: 0F
val result = initialValue + expiredSum
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code is not doing what you want

> calculate the sum of all elements with the status EXPIRED (if they exist) and add to this sum amount of the first object with the type WAIT (if it exists)

It calculates the sum of all elements with the status EXPIRED (if they exist) and add to this sum amount of the first object with the type WAIT located after the last object with EXPIRED status (if it exists) OR amount of the object with index one (if it exist) if there were no elements with status EXPIRED:

```kotlin
println(getRestructuringAmountToPay(listOf(Test("EXPIRED", 1f), Test("WAIT", 1f), Test("EXPIRED", 1f)))) //will print 2.0, while following original description it should be 3.0
println(getRestructuringAmountToPay(listOf(Test("WAIT", 1f), Test("WAIT", 100f)))) //Will print 100.0, while following original description it should be 1.0
```

To get originally desired behavior in Kotlin-way you need to do the following:

```
if (list == null) return 0f //get rid of nullability
val (expired, waiting) = list.partition { it.status != "WAIT" } //split original list into respectful partitions
val sum = expired.map { it.amount }.sum() + (waiting.firstOrNull()?.amount ?: 0f) //do the calculations
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure I understand your solution but respectively to your goal this:

```
    var sum = list.filter { it.status == "EXPIRED" }.sumByDouble { it.amount.toDouble() }
    list.firstOrNull{ it.status == "WAIT" }?.let { sum+=it.amount}

    println(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty is subjective - the code below is short but admittedly does not take advantage  of the "sorted" nature of the collection

```kotlin
fun sum(data: List<Test>): Double {
    val expiredSum = data.filter { it.status == "EXPIRED" }.sumByDouble { it.amount }
    val waitSum = data.find { it.status == "WAIT" }?.amount ?: 0.0
    return expiredSum + waitSum
}
```